# where does the href inside an <a> tag link direct me?

Tags: hyperlink, eldarion-ajax

If I were to put

```
 <a href="replace"> Replace this </a>
```

where does this link go to? I am using eldarion-ajax and the examples all use this link location.

Does this link to replace.html? 
the div with id #replace

Comment: If it was `<a href="#replace">`, it would scroll to anchor named `replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably just goes to the url "replace". like if you're at `www.website.com/index.html` it would go to `www.website.com/replace`. It's probably just a placeholder indicating you should replace it with another value.

Web URLs do not need to end in `.html` or such.